# CSS expand transition when child element sizes increase

Tags: html, css, vue.js, vuetify.js, transition

I am using Vuetify and have a v-list-item with a title and a subtitle. But the title length is limited to only show one line. If the title is longer it will be cut off and show "...".
If I click the list item i want the subtitle to disappear and show the full title instead. This might result in a new height of the whole v-list-item. The expansion of the height should be a transition so that the height is not hopping when I am clicking the list item. I have trouble to solve this problem so maybe you have some ideas. This is my code so far:

```html
<v-list-item three-line :class="{ activeListItem: currentPostId === post.id }">
   <v-list-item-content>
      <v-list-item-title :class="{'full-text': currentPostId === post.id}">
         Title
      </v-list-item-title>
      <v-list-item-subtitle :class="{ 'post-subtitle-hidden': currentPostId === post.id }">
         Subtitle
      </v-list-item-subtitle>
   </v-list-item-content>
</v-list-item>
```

CSS:

```css
.activeListItem {
   background-color: #c4e0ff !important;
}
.full-text {
   white-space: normal;
}
.post-subtitle-hidden {
   display: none;
}
.v-list-item__subtitle, .v-list-item__title {
   -webkit-box-flex: 1;
   -ms-flex: 1 1 100%;
   flex: 1 1 100%;
   overflow: hidden;
   text-overflow: ellipsis;
   white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `display: none` use `max-height: 0` then on the active class give it a `max-height` of like 100px (the maximum height you think it will ever use) than add a `transition` on `max-height`

that way it will have a sliding effect

--- edit ---
snippet for what is discussed in the comments

```js
$('.title').click(function() {
    $('.subtitle').toggleClass("subtitle-show");
});
```

```css
.subtitle {
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height .3s;
}

.subtitle-show {
  max-height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="title">
  Title
</div>
  <div class="subtitle">
      The subtitle
  </div>
</div>
```

When I click on the title the subtitle appears/disappears the only problem with this implementation is that when you close it you have a little delay because it is transitioning on the max-height 100px to 0

As far as I know there is no better way to do this in css.

Comment: You mean .post-subtitle-hidden should have max-height: 0 and I have to create a class like .post-subtitle with max-height: 100px and transition? I tried this but it is not working

Comment: Yeah that is what I meant but the transition has to be on a class that is always on the element so instead of creating a `.post-subtitle-hidden` class create a `.post-subtitle-show` class and add the `max-height: 100px;` on that and add that class to it instead of removing the hidden class

Comment: @Fynn I've added a snippet to my answer to show you how it works